# Sort SharePoint Folder Content by Date

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am extremely new to SharePoint.  What I need to do is have a folder's content sort by date.  We have a list of Automated Reports, which is really a list of different report folders.  I need this list to sort by name (which it is).  However; I need to be able to sort the files inside each folder to sort by Date - Descending.  I created a View and I thought I was assigning it to a specific folder, but the entire list of Automated Reports sorted by date.

So, my questions are:  Should I be using a View?  And, if so, how to I assign it to a specific folder?  And, if not, what should I be doing to set the files to always sort in Descending Date order?

Also, please note:  I'm not sure if the version of SharePoint we're using is 2007 or 2010.  Best guess is 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine found a simple solution for that.

You need to create a site column of type **Date and Time**, and assign **Today's date** to it. Then, you append this site column to the **Document** content type, and make the sorting view first by the field **Today**, then by **Title**.

The Folder content type won't have the Today site column, so, it will sort by title. When you upload a document inside a folder, you will have your sorting settings by the Today column.